# Sony Vaio Laptop Keys of the Num Pad in Right not working, Model NO. VPCEB45FG

Tags: laptop, hotkeys, sony-vaio, numlock

**Premise:**

1. I got my Mother Board changed today.
2. The whole Inbuilt Keyboard cab be seen as made with two fragments - QWERTY Part on Left hand-side + Num Pad on Right Handside.

Previously:
When NUM Lock was enabled the "Num Pad on Right Handside" was used to type numbers, but "NUM LOCK" enabling and disabling had no impact on the QWERTY Keyboard/KeyPad function.

Currently: NUM PAD doesn't work whatsoever. When NUM LOCK is OFF, the  QWERTY keypad misbehaves. The "M", for example, types numerical number "0" → Zero.

What could be the fix, I want:

1. Qwerty Keypad should not have an impact from enabling/disabling NUM Lock, and
2. Num pad should type numerical letters.

Comment: I would return to the place that serviced the machine and ask what happened.

Comment: That is 75KM away.

Comment: External Keyboard works fine.

Comment: So it is a hardware issue that needs repair.

Comment: OK, SO it has nothing to do with drivers, etc? Either the Keypad needs to be changed or some motherboard issue? May be external Keyboard has the correct drivers installed and "inbuilt" has some driver issue?

Comment: yes for sure  ...

Comment: I posted an answer for you and I hope you will mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NUM PAD doesn't work whatsoever. When NUM LOCK is OFF, the QWERTY
> keypad misbehaves.

Based on your post, the machine should be returned to the placed that serviced it if at all possible.

Your further information that an external keyboard works, the keyboard or some remaining hardware issue with the replaced motherboard is the problem.

Service is again required.

Comment: Visited service center, they replaced the mother board.